# XAMPP virtualhost site with all configs not working

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am trying to run site my.com locally on XAMPP's apache server. Here my configurations in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file in the path `...\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/IDEs/XAMPP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "D:/IDEs/XAMPP/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/IDEs/Websites/my.com"
    ServerName my.com
    <Directory "D:/IDEs/Websites/my.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I remembered to add two lines in the `hosts` file, with is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   my.com
```

However, when I enter via link 'my.com' with enabled apache server, I've got only page with folder directories, which are in `htdocs` XAMPP's folder.

I have checked a lot of videos and stackoverflow questions, but nothing helped.
I would be pleased if you could help me with solving this issue.

Comment: Is this file being loaded in the main apache config? I seem to remember it being commented out by default...

Comment: @MatthewPage Yeap! If we are talking about `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. i've uncommented it in the `httpd.conf` file

Comment: My next step would be comment out the xamp vh and see if yours works..

Comment: @MatthewPage nothing change, directories still appears

Comment: Did you restart apache? :)

Comment: @MatthewPage of course :) I am not a newbie in programming :)

Comment: Got to check the basics... back into httpd.conf and comment out anything hosting those default docs, see if you can force it to use your settings. apache can be a cow and I found xampp to be really bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After five days-night of reading, searching, trying, I finnally fould the solution and done it in some steps:

First of all, forget about every file, and concentrate on the `httpd-ssl.conf` which is located in `D:\IDEs\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra`.

Second:
find the line "SSL Virtual Host Context" which has been commented. And below, find the line `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`.or simmilar. Then change it to `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

Third, change document root to the path of xampp's htdocs, for example, "D:/XAMPP/htdocs". Also, change ServerName from `www.example.com:443` or similar, to localhost.
Here we done.

And Finally, after line `</VirtualHost>`, insert code

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "D:/IDEs/Websites/my.com"
        ServerName my.com
    <Directory "D:/IDEs/Websites/my.com">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change `Document Root` and `Directory` paths to your website location. And Servername to your server name.

RESTART APACHE

it works for me.

I also understood than some website uses SSL on localhost while the others not.
SO if you have exception like `Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2p PHP/7.0.33 Server at my.com Port 443` you shold add your virtualhost configs into `httpd-ssl.conf` file.
If you got like `... Port 80` add yourl virtualhost configs into `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Answer (score 1):

first you should arrange directories on httpd.conf

example:

```
    <Directory "C:/SERVER~1/web/site1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/SERVER~1/web/site2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and then arrange vhosts.conf like this

example :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/SERVER~1/web/site1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/SERVER~1/web/site1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/SERVER~1/web/site2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/SERVER~1/web/site2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you probably missing something very little